# How to override mouse press on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, pywin32

I'm programming a auto clicker in python for something and there is a program when I launch it, it blocks all the clicks that executes in the python auto clicker program that I made.
I don't know how to bypass it, what do I need to do?

The auto clicker works fine 100% ok, I tested it in clicking speed test but when I launch the other program it cancels the clicks from the auto clicker program but everything else works, the print method, changing variables all good just disables the clicks

That code is on python (it's a bit messy — it's my friend's code)

```
import win32api, win32con
import time
import random
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode
print("Welcome To The Best Undtected AutoClicker To Activate Preess Z And To Activate Press Mouse 3 For Toggle And Mouse 4 For While Clicked")
state_left = win32api.GetKeyState(0x06)  # Left button down = 0 or 1. Button up = -127 or -128
state_right = win32api.GetKeyState(0x5A)  # Right button down = 0 or 1. Button up = -127 or -128
clicked = False
zclicked = False
button = Button.left
mouse = Controller()
clicked1 = False


def click():
    i = random.randint(2, 15)
    i = i / 100
    mouse.click(button)
    time.sleep(i)


while True:
    a = win32api.GetKeyState(0x06)
    b = win32api.GetKeyState(0x5A)
    if a != state_left:  # Button state changed
        state_left = a
        if a < 0:
            clicked = True
        else:
            clicked = False

    if b != state_right:  # Button state changed
        state_right = b
        if b < 0:
            if (zclicked == True):
                zclicked = False
                print("Z Button Is Off")
            elif (zclicked == False):
                zclicked = True
                print("Z Button Is On")
    if (clicked == True and zclicked == True and clicked1==False):
        click()
    if zclicked == True and win32api.GetKeyState(0x05) == 1:
        clicked1 = True
    elif (win32api.GetKeyState(0x5) == -0 and zclicked == True and clicked==False):
        clicked1 = False
    if (clicked1 == True):
        click()

    time.sleep(0.001)
```

The other program disables the code `mouse.click(button)` in `click()` method and I need to bypass this somehow.

Comment: Google shows 13,110,000,000 results for `The other program`. Can you be a bit more specific? It would also be good to post your own code (that must be superior) since your friends code is _a bit messy_.

Comment: What's the other program?